# How do I sort array contents?

Tags: intellij-idea

From https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/ I see that there is a new action called "Sort array content" action.

However, that action does not appear; even when enabling *all* Java inspections I neither get a warning nor an action suggesting that.

How can I enable it?

I'm trying on the following array:

```
String[] sortMe = {
        "World",
        "Hello",
        "ABC"
};
```

Having it private static final and inside the class does help either.

I'm using Intellij Ultimate Build #IU-181.4203.550, build on March 26, 2018.

*Is the "Sort array content" actually just a lie?*

Answer (score 0):

I had to select one of the `String`s, then it appeared. Didn't work to just have the cursor on `sortMe`.